# apt-get install libffi-dev can't connect

Tags: apt, package-management

I run `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` and I get the following error:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libffi-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 291 not upgraded.
Need to get 161 kB of archives.
After this operation, 365 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://ftp.tecnoera.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 libffi-dev amd64 3.2.1-4
  Could not connect to ftp.tecnoera.com:80 (190.113.0.250), connection timed out
E: Failed to fetch http://ftp.tecnoera.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libffi/libffi-dev_3.2.1-4_amd64.deb  Could not connect to ftp.tecnoera.com:80 (190.113.0.250), connection timed out

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I think the url might be broken and that I should use another one but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the mirrors in 'Software Sources' to the default settings solved the problem. It seems that ftp.tecnoera.com was not working at all at the moment.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JViVr.png)

Answer (score 0):

The `libffi-dev` package seems to exist in a couple of repositories, so you might have to specify *which one* to get it from.

You can do it like this:

1. Open a terminal and type: `apt-cache showpkg libffi-dev`
2. In the `Versions` section of the output, look for a version that comes from `ubuntu.com` and identify the version number. It will look something like `1:20090909-1`
3. Use the version number when performing the install as `{package}={version}`: `sudo apt install libffi.dev=1:20090909-1`

This should give you what you’re looking for.

***Important:** The version number here is an example. I do not have a Xenial installation to provide you accurate numbers with.*

Comment: Better way is to use packages.ubuntu.com - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libffi-dev&searchon=names .